# Where to find the keychain stored by KeychainSwift

Tags: iphone, ios, keychain

I use [KeychainSwift](https://github.com/evgenyneu/keychain-swift) to store my user's keychain data using my created iOS app.

**The question is:**
Where can I see the data it stored?

I already tried going to

> Settings -> Password & Accounts -> Website and App passwords

but I can't find my application there.
I'm use an iPhone 6 as my device.

Answer (score 0):

The keychain data is saved in library/keychains/ network/library/keychains. The first location personal keychain is saved. To reach their data, I need the Keychain Utility located in the Utilities folder in the Applications folder.

Comment: but I'm using iphone, I think your answer was to get the keychain data on mac